# What is wrong with my Calculated Field Fomula?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula

I have a requirement for a workflow concatenate from several list columns into a single multi-line text column. One of the columns is a Managed meta-data column so I have to parse the data into a text string first.

To do this I have the metadata field called Ward, a text field called WardCopy and a workflow action which updates WardCopy with the contents of Ward when the list is updated.

This results in entries in WardCopy which look like this: SOMEDATA|1234-5678-91011

So I need a third field, this time a calculated column, to trim the Pipe symbol and GUID so my workflow can concat the finished data.

Here is the formula I worked out for my calculated column:

```
=LEFT( [WardCopy] , FIND(“|”,[WardCopy])-1 )
```

When I try to create the field SharePoint tells me I have a syntax error and throws me back to the column creation menu. Can anyone see where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Are you on a non-english system and need ; instead of ,
- Those double quotes aren't correct either (but could be because of copy/pasting here)

This works for me:

```
=LEFT( [WardCopy] , FIND("|",[WardCopy])-1 )
```

Comment: No it's not a non-english system. It was the double quotes. I wrote the formula out in notepad and copy/pasted it into my browser and the speach marks got converted to open and closed quotes.

Thanks for the help :)